# Loop through array of PDF files online and copy text from each

Tags: r

I see it is super-easy to grab a PDF file, save it, and fetch all the text from the file.

```
library(pdftools)
download.file("http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/085-30.pdf", "sample.pdf", mode = "wb")
txt <- pdf_text("sample.pdf")
```

I am wondering how to loop through an array of PDF files, based on links, download each, and scrape the test from each.  I want to go to the following link.

http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/toc.html#dp

Then I want to download each file from 'Paper 085-30:' to 'Paper 095-30:'.  Finally, I want to scrape the text out of each file.  How can I do that?

I would think it would be something like this, but I suspect the paste function is not setup correctly.

```
library(pdftools)
for(i in values){'085-30',' 086-30','087-30','088-30','089-30'
paste(download.file("http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/"i".pdf", i".pdf", mode = "wb")sep = "", collapse = NULL)
}
```

Comment: The `paste` call looks like it's got some commas missing. Sticking paths together is often easier/less error-prone with `sprintf`. Try `download.file(sprintf("http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/%s.pdf", i), mode = "wb")`

Comment: Ijust tried that and got this error: Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Comment: So check for where you have an extra '}'...I'm also not sure what's up with having a series of strings after your opening bracket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of pdfs using `rvest`.

```
library(rvest)

x <- read_html("http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/toc.html#dp")
href <- x %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_attr("href")

 # char vector of links, use regular expression to fetch only papers
links <- href[grepl("^http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/\\d{3}.*\\.pdf$", href)]
```

I've added some error handling and don't forget to put R session to sleep so you don't flood the server. In case a download is unsuccessful, the link is stored into a variable which you can investigate after the loop has finished and perhaps adapt your code or just download them manually.

```
# write failed links to this variable
unsuccessful <- c()

for (link in links) {
  out <- tryCatch(download.file(url = link, destfile = basename(link), mode = "wb"), 
                  error = function(e) e, warning = function(w) w)

  if (class(out) %in% c("simpleError", "simpleWarning")) {
    message(sprintf("Unable to download %s ?", link))
    unsuccessful <- c(unsuccessful, link)
  }

  sleep <- abs(rnorm(1, mean = 10, sd = 10))
  message(sprintf("Sleeping for %f seconds", sleep))
  Sys.sleep(sleep) # don't flood the server, sleep for a while 
}
```

Comment: @ryguy72 this is the same error you get with camille's code. Consider checking how you run the code and if you've copy/pasted everything down to the t.

Comment: This definitely doesn't work in my office; everything is blocked by my firm's firewall.  I am home now, and trying the code, and getting the same error as before.  I can get 'links' script working just fine; everything with that works well.  I have used that concept before; I should have thought about that earlier.  I just can't get the second part to work.  If it works for you, Roman, but doesn't work for me, that's fine.  I was just trying to learn more about this concept.  It's just a learning exercise for me.  I don't need to do this for any reason, other than for educational purposes.

Comment: I copied/pasted everything just as you described.  Something is off, on my side I guess. I'm not sure what the problems is though.

Comment: @ryguy72 as the curly brace error indicates, there's a syntax error or incorrectly ran code. In this case, it was the former. I've removed the closing brace which was offending. Try now.

Comment: Yeah!!!  Now it's working.  This is very, very very cool.  Thanks so much.

Comment: I wish the debugger in R  Studio was a little more user friendly.  I love the one in Visual Studio (C# and VB) and the one in Excel/Access is very nice too.  The one in R Studio is cumbersome, and very lacking, at best.  Also, I'm just not good at debugging R code and Python code.  Anyway, thanks for the help with everything.